# Application is running correctly but when try to build jar "org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException"

Tags: spring-boot, executable-jar, spring-jdbc

**UserRepo.java**

```
package com.sample.sample.repository;

import com.sample.sample.entity.User;
import com.sample.sample.model.UserModel;
import org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;

@Repository
public interface UserRepo extends PagingAndSortingRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> getUserByEmail(String email);

    Optional<User> getUserByPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :userName OR phone_number = :userName")
    Optional<User> get_user_by_user_name(String userName);

    Optional<User> findById(Long id);
}
```

**SecurityConfig.java**

```
package com.sample.sample.config;

import com.sample.sample.security.CustomUserDetailsService;
import com.sample.sample.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint;
import com.sample.sample.security.TokenAuthenticationFilter;
import com.sample.sample.security.oauth2.CustomOAuth2UserService;
import com.sample.sample.security.oauth2.HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;
import com.sample.sample.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.sample.sample.security.oauth2.OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.config.BeanIds;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(
        securedEnabled = true,
        jsr250Enabled = true,
        prePostEnabled = true
)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private CustomOAuth2UserService customOAuth2UserService;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    private HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository httpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository;

    @Bean
    public TokenAuthenticationFilter tokenAuthenticationFilter() {
        return new TokenAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    /*
      By default, Spring OAuth2 uses HttpSessionOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository to save
      the authorization request. But, since our service is stateless, we can't save it in
      the session. We'll save the request in a Base64 encoded cookie instead.
    */
    @Bean
    public HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository() {
        return new HttpCookieOAuth2AuthorizationRequestRepository();
    }

    @Override

    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(customUserDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }


    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .cors()
                    .and()
                .sessionManagement()
                    .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
                    .and()
                .csrf()
                    .disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .disable()
                .httpBasic()
                    .disable()
                .exceptionHandling()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(new RestAuthenticationEntryPoint())
                    .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/",
                        "/error",
                        "/favicon.ico",
                        "/**/*.png",
                        "/**/*.gif",
                        "/**/*.svg",
                        "/**/*.jpg",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js")
                        .permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/auth/**", "/oauth2/**")
                        .permitAll()
                    .anyRequest()
                        .permitAll()
                    .and()
                .oauth2Login()
                    .authorizationEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/authorize")
                        .authorizationRequestRepository(cookieAuthorizationRequestRepository())
                        .and()
                    .redirectionEndpoint()
                        .baseUri("/oauth2/callback/*")
                        .and()
                    .userInfoEndpoint()
                        .userService(customOAuth2UserService)
                        .and()
                    .successHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                    .failureHandler(oAuth2AuthenticationFailureHandler);

        // Add our custom Token based authentication filter
        http.addFilterBefore(tokenAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }
}
```

**CustomUserDetailsService.java**

```
package com.sample.sample.security;


import com.sample.sample.exception.ResourceNotFoundException;
import com.sample.sample.entity.User;
import com.sample.sample.repository.UserRepo;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;


@Component
    public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    UserRepo userRepo;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName)
            throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.get_user_by_user_name(userName)
                .orElseThrow(() ->
                        new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found with email or password : " + userName)
        );

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }

    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserById(Long id) {
        User user = userRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(
            () -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User", "id", id)
        );

        return UserPrincipal.create(user);
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.6.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.sample.sample</groupId>
    <artifactId>sample</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Sample</name>
    <description>Online Confectionary API</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.0-M5</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.22</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
            <artifactId>flyway-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JWT library -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- DO NOT include log4j.properties file in your Jar -->
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/log4j.properties</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <!-- Jar file entry point -->
                            <mainClass>com.sample.sample.Application</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

**Error**

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency
> expressed through field 'customUserDetailsService'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'userRepo' defined in
> com.sample.sample.repository.UserRepo defined in
> @EnableJdbcRepositories declared on
> JdbcRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJdbcRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'refreshEventListener' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'refreshEventListener'
> parameter 0; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'configDataContextRefresher' defined in class
> path resource
> [org/springframework/cloud/autoconfigure/RefreshAutoConfiguration.class]:
> Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
> instantiate
> [org.springframework.cloud.context.refresh.ConfigDataContextRefresher]:
> Factory method 'configDataContextRefresher' threw exception; nested
> exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/springframework/boot/ConfigurableBootstrapContext     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:643)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:897)
> ~[spring-beans-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]     at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:879)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:551)
> ~[spring-context-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:758)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:750)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:405)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
> ~[spring-boot-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]    at
> org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:120)
> ~[spring-boot-test-2.3.6.RELEASE.jar:2.3.6.RELEASE]   at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:123)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.setUpRequestContextIfNecessary(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:190)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(ServletTestExecutionListener.java:132)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:244)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:98)
> ~[spring-test-5.2.11.RELEASE.jar:5.2.11.RELEASE]  at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:346)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:341)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
> ~[na:na]  at
> java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658)
> ~[na:na]  at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:340)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:263)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$2(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:256)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]    at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$3(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:255)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:29)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:108)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:107)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:71)
> ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.3.jar:5.6.3]   at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$1(NodeTestTask.java:107)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:107)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:75)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
> at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
> ~[junit-platform-engine-1.6.3.jar:1.6.3]  at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:220)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:188)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:202)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:181)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
> org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
> ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]    at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invokeAllTests(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:150)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformProvider.invoke(JUnitPlatformProvider.java:124)
> ~[surefire-junit-platform-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:384)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:345)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.execute(ForkedBooter.java:126)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]  at
> org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:418)
> ~[surefire-booter-2.22.2.jar:2.22.2]

Application is Running correctly , but when I try to build the jar , the above error occurred , please someone help me on this,
what is the problem here , whether I have missed something ?

Comment: please provide your pom or gradle file and explain how you run and build the project.

Comment: @grekier I have provided my pom.xml and I use mvn clean and mvn package to build jar

Comment: @grekier 

this is the error when I run the jar file 

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customUserD
etailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'customUserDetailsService': Unsatisfied dependency e
xpressed through field 'userRepo'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreation

Comment: Problem seems to be `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/ConfigurableBootstrapContext` but this class came in 2.4 and you are using 2.3 so there is a mismatch somewhere. Easiest way to fix this is probably to upgrade to 2.4...

Comment: @grekier Thank you very much , Now it is fixed by upgrading to 2.4 version